# What is the most efficient way to store a formula in SQL server, then PHP calculates and stores results?

Tags: php, sql, formula

I have a web app that needs to store 96 months of volumes. These volumes can be based on a calculation of other volumes. So, let's say `[Volume_A] = [Volume_B]*2`. If `[Volume_B]` changes, the calculation needs to be re-performed to change the value of [Volume_A]. So, pretty much the same functionality as Excel. `[Volume_B]` can vary across the 96 months, so I can't apply the result of month 1 to month 96.

My current solution is to create the full SQL update query from the formula and store it in my SQL server DB. Then, it is triggered when `[Volume_B]` is changed. Problem is that the query can get pretty big when the formula becomes quite complex and it takes too long to process. In addition, I can have hundreds of these formulas in each session, slowing the recalc down even more.

Is there a better to get the same result? That is, when [Volume_B] changes, `[Volume_A]` changes. Storing and processing the full SQL query just seems a bit clumsy. There must be a better way ... Been scratching my head for a while about this.

Is there some 3rd party plug-in or something? Any thoughts/leads greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Is there some 3rd party plug-in or something? ` is off topic for SO. I would focus the question to `takes too long to process`. Can you add a schema to the question and some samples of what takes a long time?

Comment: Have you looked into [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)?

Comment: Maybe I’m missing the point, but if volume B is an historic value and volume A is calculated, then why bother saving/updating volume A? Just calculate it as you need it. And if volume B is some monthly value, why are you changing values when you could just add another row?  It’s a bit unclear what you’re trying to do.